# fadeIn all <em></em>

Tags: jquery, html

I feel stupid dumb for asking this question but I am trying to set all text tagged w/ em around it, to fade in.

```
$('em').fadeIn('slow', function() {
  // Animation complete
});

<em>Fade in</em>
```

Comment: What's *not* happening at the moment?

Comment: Are the elements actually hidden before you try to fade them in?

Comment: @nick - anything within em tags are not fading in

@rotora - Not hidden

Comment: fadeIn only fades in elements that aren't already visible.

Comment: Well then, how about hiding them first? :) `style="display: none"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do a fade-in effect with `<em>` tags that aren't hidden, consider this:

```
$('em').hide();
$('em').fadeIn('slow', function() {
  // Animation complete
});
```

However, you're probably better off hiding the `<em>` tags first using CSS.  In general, jQuery will ignore requests to do things that are already done, like fading/hiding elements that are not visible or scaling elements to a size that matches their current dimensions.

Comment: thanks. 

$('em').hide();
$('em').fadeIn(4000, function() {
  // Animation complete
});

Comment: You might even be able to chain it to this:  `$('em').hide().fadeIn(4000, function() { // Animation complete });` You'll have to try that, not sure if jQuery will fire off both of those.

Answer (score 0):

Hide them first. Like this for instance (hard to suggest better without more info)

```
$('em').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```